# Backtracking all answers

Tags: c, recursion, sudoku, backtracking

I have this code here. It works fine when you're solving for a solution to a sudoku problem.

```
int solveBoard(int board[SIZE][SIZE], int rowPos, int colPos) {
    int newValueToCheck, oldRowPos, oldColPos;
    if (rowPos == SIZE) return 1;
    if (board[rowPos][colPos] != 0) {
        if (colPos == SIZE - 1) {
            rowPos++;
            colPos = 0;
        } else colPos++;
        if (solveBoard(board, rowPos, colPos) == 1) return 1;
        return 0;
    } for (newValueToCheck = 1; newValueToCheck <= SIZE; newValueToCheck++)
        if (checkBoard(board, newValueToCheck, rowPos, colPos) == 1) {
            board[rowPos][colPos] = newValueToCheck;
            oldRowPos = rowPos; 
            oldColPos = colPos;
            if (colPos == SIZE - 1) {
                rowPos++;
                colPos = 0;
            } else colPos++;
            if (solveBoard(board, rowPos, colPos) == 1) return 1;
            rowPos = oldRowPos;
            colPos = oldColPos;
            board[rowPos][colPos] = 0;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Only thing is, I'd like to get all possible answers. How will I modify this and get all the possible answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't backtrack the search when a solution has been found. So, make a simple recursive call at the place you try new values and ignore its return value:

```
solveBoard(board, rowPos, colPos);
```

and then you every solution at the tail of the recursion:

```
if (rowPos == SIZE) printSolution(); return 1;
```

Comment: i think you should remove `return1;`

so that you still can print the next ones.